# Some files have been marked for deletion in SVN status, how do I undo that?

Tags: svn

When I do `svn status`, I get a bunch of

```
D        mydir/myfile
```

Does it mean that at some point I must have done `svn rm`? This sounds unlikely, given that I had never had these files locally to begin with, as far as I know.

More importantly, now my `svn update` does not update these files. How do I get them into my local directory tree?

Addin

Answer (score 2):

To reverse a change that has been made in a working copy but not yet committed, use [`svn revert`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve.revert). In this case, `svn revert mydir/myfile`

Comment: But won't that, in general case, undo all changes in the files themselves? What if I just want to unmark the deletion?

Comment: Yes, but subversion doesn't track uncommitted changes. If you make changes then mark for deletion, svn only knows how to restore to the last known repository state.